# Perl return match string ignoring the ending delimiter if it exists

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

I'm trying to get a pattern match in perl where i check for 'Non-White space characters in the beginning of a line that i read from file, and return the first matched word.

Problem is, sometimes i will have the word ending with a ':' sometimes i will not.

For Eg:

Assume i have a file with the following content. Sometimes with the alternate content. The file is automatically populated.

```
some0 Loren Posem:is some color::and some foo bar with 1023:4632
      some more content added to the file
some3 Loren Posem:is some color::and some foo bar with 1023:4632
      some more content added to the file
```

Alternate content:

```
some1: Loren Posem:is some will be different with some number 5423:32
      some more content added to the file
some3: Loren Posem:is some will be different with some number 5423:32
      some more content added to the file
```

Now i want to extract only the first word from this file. But if the file has the alternate content, i still just want the first word ignoring the trailing ':'.

I only need the pattern matching part here.
This what i got so far.

```
foreach ... 
    if  (/^(\S+):/) { 
        print $1;
    }
```

/* If i use the above pattern match i'm getting the first word from alternate content i.e some1 and some3 ignoring the trailing ":" but when the i have the original content $1 is not matched.
*/

But if i use

```
foreach ... 
    if  (/^(\S+)/) { 
        print $1;
    }
```

/* Now the alternate content won't be matched. */

Any tips here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a lot of data to process, `split`ting (and setting `split`'s LIMIT) to get the first word can provide a significant performance edge over a capturing regex, in this case:

```
foreach ... 
    if (  my $firstWord = ( split /[:\s]/, $_, 2 )[0] ) {
    print $firstWord, "\n";
}
```

[Benchmark](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw/cmpthese/;

my @data = <DATA>;

sub _split {
    for (@data) {
        if ( my $firstWord = ( split /[:\s]/, $_, 2 )[0] ) {
            #print $firstWord, "\n";
        }
    }
}

sub _regex {
    for (@data) {
        if ( my ($firstWord) = /^([^:\s]+)/ ) {
            #print $firstWord, "\n";
        }
    }
}

cmpthese(
    -5,
    {
        _split => sub { _split() },
        _regex => sub { _regex() }
    }
);

__DATA__
some0 Loren Posem:is some color::and some foo bar with 1023:4632
some3 Loren Posem:is some color::and some foo bar with 1023:4632
some1: Loren Posem:is some will be different with some number 5423:3
some3: Loren Posem:is some will be different with some number 5423:32
```

Output (faster times are lower in the table):

```
           Rate _regex _split
_regex 396843/s     --   -12%
_split 450546/s    14%     --
```

However, you may find the regex more readable.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i still see the trailing ":" when i print $1, but i don't want that ':'

Comment: @devgp - Yes and this has been modified by suggesting to use `split` instead of a capturing regex.

Answer (score 2):

Greedy matching exluding spaces and colons:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    if  (/^([^:\s]+)/) { 
        print "$1\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
some0 Loren Posem:is some color::and some foo bar with 1023:4632
      some more content added to the file
some3 Loren Posem:is some color::and some foo bar with 1023:4632
      some more content added to the file
Alternate content:

some1: Loren Posem:is some will be different with some number 5423:32
      some more content added to the file
some3: Loren Posem:is some will be different with some number 5423:32
      some more content added to the file
```